# Cannot enable HiDPI from Gnome Tweak Tool?

Tags: gnome3, display, display-settings, wayland

In past Fedora releases, the Gnome Tweak Tool can be used to turn on HiDPI for Retina displays. However, I found the option missing in Fedora 27 (at least for the beta version I’m using, but it doesn’t feel like this is an issue of the beta).

[image]

While trying workarounds, I found this command to be working: (effective after login again)

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor 2
```

But this command does not have good support for some apps, such as Firefox and even the system file browser. I believe there should be some graphical way to do this, am I right?

Answer (score 8):

Apparently it's been removed from `Tweaks` but not from `dconf` which is why you're still able to do it via terminal... Typical GNOME stuff.
Anyway, as of `gnome 3.26`, [there's a new `dconf` key under `org.gnome.mutter`](https://github.com/GNOME/mutter/blob/master/data/org.gnome.mutter.gschema.xml.in) called `experimental-features` which is of type `as` (array of strings - it accepts multiple string values) and one particular value enables HiDpi support on `Wayland` (including fractional values):

```
• "scale-monitor-framebuffer" — makes mutter default to layout logical monitors
                                in a logical pixel coordinate space, while scaling
                                monitor framebuffers instead of window content, to
                                manage HiDPI monitors. Does not require a restart.
```

So per the above, fire up `dconf-editor` and add `'scale-monitor-framebuffer'` to the list of experimental features under `org.gnome.mutter`:

[image]

For those who prefer the terminal, [follow the instructions here](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Mutter/RemoteDesktop) (sure, replacing the values in that example: `'screen-cast', 'remote-desktop'` with `'scale-monitor-framebuffer'`).
Restart your session and you should then be able to set the scaling factor from the control center
*Settings* > *Devices* > *Displays* > *Scale*:

[image]

Comment: Is the removal of Scaling setting in Tweak a temporary decision because some bugs found, or is it because a change in the design of Tweak? Thanks!

Comment: I changed the value to `["scale-monitor-framebuffer"]` and restarted the VM. But I don't see the Scale setting. On the other hand, I think a 200% scaling would be great for my display, is it possible to do it this way (since the maximum is 150% in your screenshot)? Thanks!

Comment: @jackxujh - 1. I don't know, I'm not a gnome dev. 2. works fine here, though it's a real setup not a VM. 3. from what I gather, the maximum scaling factor varies, the higher the native resolution the higher the max.

Comment: I guess then it has something to do with the VM tool messing around with resolution settings. I do feel that there should be at least a 125% or higher option for the MacBook Pro's 2880*1800 resolution.

Comment: @jackxujh - on a MBP you should have at least up to 200% scaling available